# Karma Code Execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

Looking at a `karma` test from [Angular in Action](http://www.manning.com/bford/), I ran the following test.

```
describe("Service: angelloModel", function() {
    // load the service's module
    beforeEach(module("Angello"));

    var modelService;

    //Initialize the service
    beforeEach(inject(function (angelloModel) {
        modelService = angelloModel;
        console.log("modelService:", modelService);
    }));

    console.log("after| modelService:", modelService);

    it("it should return seven different statuses", function() {
                console.log("it: modelService", modelService);
                ...
    });
});
```

The console logged:

```
    after| modelService: undefined 
    modelService: Object ...
    it: modelService Object ..
```

Is `modelService` undefined since the `console.log` executed *before* running the `beforeEach` that sets the `modelService`?

Lastly, does the `it(...)` function have `modelService`'s `Object` value since `karma` calls `beforeEach`, and then runs `it`?

Answer (score 1):

Er, yes and yes.

If you'd like a little more detail, here's a minimal code sample that demonstrates the things you're asking about:

```
describe('suite', function() {

    var foo;

    beforeEach(function() {
       foo = 'bar';
    });

    console.log('foo: ' + foo);

    it('test', function() {
        console.log('foo: ' + foo);
    });

}
```

The test *runner* (Karma in this case) has two distinct phases: test definition and test execution.

During the test definition phase, the test *script* will be executed, which will result in the construction of an internal data structure containing the tests and suites.

1. The `describe` api of the test *framework* will be called; this api will make some record of the suite name and call the function passed as its second argument.
2. The `beforeEach` api will be called; this api will associate the function passed as its argument with the immediately enclosing test suite, but will *not* execute it.
3. The `console.log` statement will be executed, logging `foo: undefined`
4. The `it` api will be called; this will make a record of the test name and the function passed as its second argument, associating them with the immediately enclosing test suite, but again, the passed function will *not* be executed.

Now the test runner will proceed to the test *execution* phase, during which the test *framework* will walk through its internal data structure and execute the defined tests. In this example:

1. The function that was passed to the `beforeEach` api will be executed, assigning the string value `'bar'` to the variable `foo`.
2. The function that was passed to the `it` api will be executed, causing `foo: bar` to be logged.

That's probably more that you really wanted to know - hope you find it useful.